# What package for loading and saving images in R

Tags: r, image-processing

I know this has been asked before but the existing answers seem out of date, as I can't install either Bio7 or rimage using install.packages and searching the cran repository for Bio7 gives a 404 link (am I missing something?).

So as of now, what are the right packages for loading / saving images in R so one can process the pixels from within R?

I don't need it to provide processing routines. As long as it can reliably turn a jpeg into a grid of pixel values and vice versa (and preferably do the same for a png) I can write processing code.

Comment: What functionality in the listed package do you want to have? there are some packages like `raster` package..`png` ``jpeg`.. Can you give more information about the context of using pixels.

Comment: Updated question. All sorts of processing on pixels from HOG filters to custom histogram mappings to custom image denoising. I can implement those though, I just need a way to get at the data and then to save it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `raster` is what you need.

```
library(png)
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
## convert it to a raster, interpolate =F to select only sample of pixels of img
img.r <- as.raster(img,interpolate=F)
```

Now you have a vector of color:

```
 str(img.r)
 'raster' chr [1:76, 1:100] "#00000000" "#0
```

Comment: And look at the jpeg package for reading in '.jpg' files.  Why do you need the grid package?

Comment: When I said a "grid of pixel values" I wasn't refering to a grid object. I just meant I can load them and get at the pixel at position (x,y), either using matrices (e.g. one per color channel) or in a single flat array by using data at something like bytes_per_pixel*(x + y * image_pixels_per_row). Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @GregSnow it is a typo. I update my answer to remove the extra line.